# How to delete the recyclerView list from my app and FireStore in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

ı am a new about Kotlin Android. I add the delete button on my app to delete recyclerView. When I click this button, ı want to to delete from recyclerview list(on my app) and also from my firestore. I created interface and setonclick listener but when ı click the delete button, it does not work. What do I miss ? What should I do? I shared below my adapter and activity code and you can see easily what ı miss. Thanx.

My adapter code;

```
class NoteAdapter(private var titleText: ArrayList<String>, private var imageButton: ArrayList<String>, private var noteText: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val itemTitle : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerTitleText)
        val itemImage : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerImage)
        val itemDelete : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete)


        init {

            itemView.setOnClickListener { v: View ->


               // Toast.makeText(itemView.context,"You clicked on item # ${position + 1}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val intent = Intent(itemView.context, PastNotesActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("oldTitle", titleText[position])
                intent.putExtra("oldNote", noteText[position])
                intent.putExtra("oldImage", imageButton[position])
                itemView.context.startActivity(intent)

            }

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.itemTitle.text = titleText[position]
        Picasso.get().load(imageButton[position]).resize(150,150).into(holder.itemImage)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return titleText.size
    }
}
```

my activity code,

```
class ListViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private  lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var db : FirebaseFirestore

    var titleTextFromFB : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    var noteTextFromFB : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    var imageFromFB : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    var adapter: NoteAdapter? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        getDataFromFirestore()

        // recyclerview

        var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        adapter = NoteAdapter(titleTextFromFB, imageFromFB, noteTextFromFB)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter


    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        val menuInflater = menuInflater
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.add_note, menu)

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        if (item.itemId == R.id.add_note_click) {
            // Take Notes Activity
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, TakeNotesActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("info","new")
            startActivity(intent)

        } else if (item.itemId == R.id.log_out) {

            val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

            alert.setTitle("Log Out")
            alert.setMessage("Are you sure to logout from the app ?")
            alert.setPositiveButton("Yes") {dialog, which ->

                auth.signOut()
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }

            alert.setNegativeButton("No") {dialog, which ->

            }

            alert.show()

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    // get data from firestore

    fun getDataFromFirestore() {

        db.collection("Notes").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->

            if (exception != null) {

                // If there is a error ,

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, exception.localizedMessage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            } else {

                if (snapshot != null) {

                    if (!snapshot.isEmpty) {

                        titleTextFromFB.clear()
                        noteTextFromFB.clear()

                        val documents = snapshot.documents
                        for (document in documents) {

                            val userEmail = document.get("userEmail") as String
                            val noteTitle = document.get("noteTitle") as String
                            val yourNote = document.get("yourNote") as String
                            val downloadUrl = document.get("downloadUrl") as String
                            val timestamp = document.get("date") as Timestamp
                            val date = timestamp.toDate()

                            titleTextFromFB.add(noteTitle)
                            imageFromFB.add(downloadUrl)
                            noteTextFromFB.add(yourNote)

                            adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                        }
                    }
                }

            }


        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement click button inside `onBindViewHolder`

Answer (score 0):

add function in adapter for remove item from items list and `notifeDataSetChanged()`